# How to get all the ids of the elements where the condition is true?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a toggling function with js to hide all comments with its children.
this is a comment in html:

```
 <div>
    <a onclick="return toggle(4 /*id*/, 7 /*lft*/, 10 /*rgt*/)" href="javascript:void(0)">[-]</a>
    <div id="com4" class="md" value="7-10">yellow</div>
 </div>
```

⬆ this comment has a child value="8-9", I want to hide the comment with id="com4" and it child.--> this is the question how to find the id where the comments where it value="8-9"

and this is my js:

```
function toggle(id, lft, rgt) {
    var kids = (rgt - lft - 1) / 2;
    if (kids >= 1) {
        var element = document.querySelectorAll("div.md").getAttribute('value');
        var low = Number(element.split('-')[0]);
        var high = Number(element.split('-')[1]);
        if (low > lft && high < rgt) {
            var x = //get the ids of these elements where: low>lft && high<rgt 
                if (x.style.display === "none") {
                    x.style.display = "block";
                } else {
                    x.style.display = "none";
                }
        }
    } else {
        var x = document.getElementById("com" + id);
        if (x.style.display === "none") {
            x.style.display = "block";
        } else {
            x.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I'm trying to find all ids of the children ⬆:

```
if (low > lft && high < rgt) {
                var x = //get the ids of these elements where: low>lft && high<rgt
```

here's an image to understand how my comment system works:
[nested sets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CryVk.png)

thanks in advance, and I'm sorry for my bad english ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a look at these codes:

```js
 function toggle(id, lft, rgt) {
    var kids = (rgt - lft - 1) / 2;
    if (kids >= 1) {
        var element = document.querySelectorAll("div.md#com" + id)[0].getAttribute('value');
        var low = Number(element.split('-')[0]);
        var high = Number(element.split('-')[1]);
        for(var i = low + 1; i <= high - 1; i += 1){
            var x = document.querySelectorAll("div.md#com" + i)[0]
            if (x.style.display === "none") {
                x.style.display = "block";
            } else {
                x.style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div id="com4" class="md" value="7-10">yellow 
        <a onclick="toggle(4, 7, 10)" href="javascript:void(0)">[-]</a>
    </div>
    
    <div id="com5" class="md">Should not collapse</div>
    <div id="com8" class="md">Should collapse</div>
    <div id="com9" class="md">Should collapse</div>
    <div id="com11" class="md">Should not collapse</div>
 </div>
```

Comment: THANK YOU a lot man, that worked but I want the value to be in between 7-10 like this:<div id="com11" class="md" value="8-9">Should collapse</div>, <div id="com8" class="md" value="10-11">Should not collapse</div>, so how to implement this?

Comment: plz can u just say how to continue?

Comment: Based on the image you've attached in your question, you have two option:

The first one is selecting those comments whose ids are between `low` and `high` which is descendant tree, exactly what you want.

The second one is arranging comments in nested matter. What I mean is putting descendant tree inside parent `div` and toggle that specific `div`. In this case you need to store `depth` of comments as well as `right` and `left`.

The former one is a bit slow but the latter one is more straightforward.